# Start vim automatically as root in home folder

Tags: vim, permissions

Is it possible to start vim automatically with root permission if I start it in my home folder (or in a subdirectory of that folder)?

Comment: Do you intend to get rid of the the password prompt? And could you specify the use case? As generally speaking, stuff in your home should belong to you and not root.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to type in my password everytime I change something on my files.

Comment: I still do not understand your use case, as what you describe still implies something terribly wrong with your file system. Again, files in your home directory should never need root rights to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a shortcut to run `sudo vim ~/.`.

Comment: But please keep in mind what **k0pernikus** said.

Comment: Generally speaking k0pernikus is correct.  If the original question doesn't care about that, they could also use the same shortcut with a modification to the /etc/sudoers file to allow this particular sudo command to execute without being prompted for a password.

Comment: Explain to me why the bash function was voted up when it does the exact same thing that my answer suggested.

Comment: No one but the one person who upvoted can explain.

Comment: Harrij, I've seen your answer. But as the qustion conained word "automatically", I sepose alias is not full answer and function is.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the description of use case is missing. But when you want to run different applications depending on target directory, bash functions are useful. For example, add to your `~/.bashrc`

```
function vim () {
  if [[ "$PWD" == "$HOME"* ]];
   then 
    sudo vim $1
   else
   vim $1
  fi
}
```